# How to show that $\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-t-xt^{-1/2})\,dt$ satisfies the differential equation $xy'''+2y=0$ with $y(0)=1, y(+\infty)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

How can I show that $$\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-t-xt^{-1/2})\,dt$$ satisfies the differential equation $xy'''+2y=0$ with boundary conditions $y(0)=1, y(+\infty)=0$.

I tried differentiating with respect to $x$ three times and then different ways of by part, but still, I could not see that it satisfies the differential equation.  The book says that it does satisfies the equation. How can I show this?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please show your attempts, then there's a better chance to get a useful answer

Comment: Only two boundary conditions are given. So, a second order ODE is expected, not a third order. Are you sure that there is no typo ?

Comment: It is the same as what is in the book. If I can upload a picture of that page, I would upload it. Assume that there is a typo in the book and the third derivative is actually a second derivative. will this integral representation satisfy the condition?